# Setting custom branded login page within singe PHP application

Tags: php, apache

I have a multi-tenant SaaS platform and a customer wants to customize the look and feel of the login page and the dashboard page.  I was able to successfully customize the dashboard page by storing the name of the CSS file to use in the ACCOUNTS table of my database.  This works because I know which account to get from the database once they log in.  However, I do not have this capability for the login page.

Is it possible to customize which CSS file or login page to use based on the DNS?  For example, customerabc.server.com gets the generic login page.  customerxyz.server.com gets their custom login page.

I am using Apache and PHP.  Thanks.

Comment: you mean URL\URI not DNS, and yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using apache vhosts.  The ServerName property needs to match the root URL/URI and to ensure that all includes are being set properly, You have to have a copy of the php.ini file in the root directory so that you can make changes to the include_path here and not affect other install instances elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just configure an apache subdomain to the same docroot and react in your application on the different domains.